# Django - Access specific field from a model to another

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create in admin panel a status field for different Models which should inherit that attribute from my main model called Students:

```
class Students(models.Model):
Username = models.ForeignKey(User)
FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
LastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Group = models.CharField(max_length=4)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1,null=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='n')
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.Username) + ' ' + self.FirstName +' ' + self.LastName
```

In CatalogStudentsFirstYear I want to store in *status* only the status value from *Students*

```
class CatalogStudentsFirstYear(models.Model):
    catalogFirstYear = models.ForeignKey(CatalogFirstYear)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    grade = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.catalogFirstYear) +' ' + str(self.student)
```

And add it to admin.py like this:

```
list_display = ["student", "catalogFirstYear", "grade", "status"]
```

This is how it looks like in Students admin panel
[image]

And this is how currently looks CatalogStudentsFirstYear [image]

Can you please suggest how can I create a FK which takes only *status* filed from Students and store it it *status* from CatalogStudentsFirstYear ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `status` as model property:

```
class CatalogStudentsFirstYear(models.Model):
    catalogFirstYear = models.ForeignKey(CatalogFirstYear)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    grade = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.catalogFirstYear) +' ' + str(self.student)

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self.student.status
```

And add this property to admin's `list_display`:

```
list_display = ["student", "catalogFirstYear", "grade", "status"]
```